# Algorithm for excluding choices

Tags: php, algorithm, combobox

First of all sorry for my bad english

I have problem with algorithm for excluding choices

I have such settings

[image]

Based on these settings, user have the option to choose 3 combo boxes

For example, my combo boxes

```
First combo------Second combo------Third combo

2-------------|-------100-------|------35

2-------------|-------100-------|------40

2-------------|-------100-------|------55

2-------------|-------100-------|------72

2-------------|-------25--------|------35

2-------------|-------25--------|------40

2-------------|-------25--------|------55
```

When I choose in first combo 2, in the second combo I need two choices 100 and 25.

When I choose in second combo 100, in the third combo I need one choices 35.

When I choose in second combo 25, in the third combo I need three choices 35 and 40 and 55.

In my DB I have serialized array ONLY with excluded ID of variants

```
a:3:{i:2;s:1:"3";i:3;s:1:"8";i:4;s:2:"10";}
a:3:{i:2;s:1:"3";i:3;s:1:"8";i:4;s:2:"11";}
a:3:{i:2;s:1:"3";i:3;s:1:"8";i:4;s:2:"12";}
```

If unserialize this arrays I'll get

```
array (size=3)
  2 => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => string '8' (length=1)
  4 => string '10' (length=2)
array (size=3)
  2 => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => string '8' (length=1)
  4 => string '11' (length=2)
array (size=3)
  2 => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => string '8' (length=1)
  4 => string '12' (length=2)
```

Please help me write code

I tried to write it myself, but to no avail:(

Apparently I'm a coder and not a programmer :(

Here is my attempt

```
<?php
function _uc_dependent_attributes_get_dependency_for_node()
{
    $nid = 61;
    if(!$nid)
        return;

    $result = db_query("SELECT combination FROM {uc_dependent_attributes} WHERE nid = :nid", array(':nid' => $nid));
    $combos = array();
    foreach($result as $record)
    {
        $combos[] = unserialize($record->combination);
    }

    $attributes = node_load($nid)->attributes;
    $attrs = array();
    foreach($attributes as $attr)
    {
        $attrs['a' . $attr->aid] = array();
        $attrs['a' . $attr->aid]['name'] = $attr->name;
        $attrs['a' . $attr->aid]['aid'] = $attr->aid;
        if(!empty($attr->options))
        {
            foreach($attr->options as $option)
            {
                $attrs['a' . $attr->aid]['options']['o' . $option->oid] = $option->name;
            }
        }
    }
    ttt($attrs, $combos, array(
        'attr_2' => 2,
        'opt_4' => 4,
    ));
}

function ttt($attrs, $combos, $selections = array())
{
    var_dump($attrs);
    var_dump($combos);

    foreach($combos as $combo)
    {
        foreach($combo as $c_aid => $c_oid)
        {
            foreach($attrs as $a_aid => $attr)
            {
                if('a' . $c_aid == $a_aid)
                {
//                    var_dump($attrs[$a_aid]['options']['o' . $c_oid]);
//                    if(isset($attrs[$a_aid]['options']['o' . $c_oid]) && 'o' . $c_oid != 'o' . $opt_id)
//                        unset($attrs[$a_aid]['options']['o' . $c_oid]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    echo '<table border="1"><tr>';
    foreach($attrs as $attr)
    {
        $sa = false;
        foreach($selections as $key_s => $selected)
        {
            if(strstr($key_s, 'attr_') !== false && $selected == $attr['aid'])
            {
                $sa = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        echo '<td>' . ($sa ? '<strong>' : '') . '(' . $attr['aid'] . ')' . $attr['name'] . ($sa ? '</strong>' : '') . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr><tr>';
    foreach($attrs as $attr)
    {
        echo '<td>';
        foreach($attr['options'] as $key => $opt)
        {
            $so = false;
            foreach($selections as $key_s => $selected)
            {
                if(strstr($key_s, 'opt_') !== false && 'o' . $selected == $key)
                {
                    $so = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            echo ($so ? '<strong>' : '') . "($key) " . $opt . ($so ? '</strong>' : '') . '<br>';
        }
        echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr></table>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve that on the client side: See http://code.google.com/p/jquery-option-tree/
If you want to achieve that on the server side, you will need a piece of JavaScript that causes a form submit each time the user selects an item in the combobox, then on the server side, you filter each combobox accordingly. I think the first solution is the easiest and most elegant. You will need to use the JQuery library though.
See http://kotowicz.net/jquery-option-tree/demo/demo.html for a demo.